# The Purpose of Base Address Randomization

Tags: visual-studio, dll, rebase

Since VS2008(Is it right?), MSVC linker option has a Base Address Randomization.

What the main purpose of this feature?

What I only glad to is, I don't need to rebase my Dlls manually anymore.

Is that all? Was it their purpose?
Is there any other benefit else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you'll find that the idea is to change the entry points making it harder to exploit them - ie now an attacker not only needs to be able get executable code into memory but also work out which addresses it should be pointing at.

See [here](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization#Benefits) for more information

Comment: But, is 'Base Address Randomization' equal to ASLR? I thought it just decides it's base address(Only!) in runtime(Randomly).

Comment: I believe the net result is the same - you're effectively adding a fixed offset to all addresses. See here: http://www.usenix.org/events/sec03/tech/full_papers/bhatkar/bhatkar_html/dao002.html which specifically refers to this as Base Address Randomisation