# Why the stack address is lower than the heap address sometimes?

Tags: c++, memory, operating-system, heap-memory, stack-memory

I always think stack locates at higher address than heap like the picture2. But I found that sometimes the heap address is higher when I test it using cpp(picture1). I know that the virtual memory is used but I also want to know why the virtual address of stack and heap dont follow the picture2? Thank you very much！

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are no rules where to put the stack and the heap.

Comment: This depends on your implementation. You would have to specify which OS and compiler you are asking about.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556348/the-purpose-of-base-address-randomization.

Comment: The picture is just *representative* – it's a way that you can think about how the items are laid out in memory. It doesn't mean that they're *always* in that order.

Comment: Does it really matter?

Comment: `z` is a constant.  There's no reason for it to be in heap or stack.

Comment: Two very related questions (although focused on Windows, the answers are essentially the same): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863194/why-is-the-stack-address-lower-than-that-of-heap-in-visual-c, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11925397/windows-stack-and-heap-address-ranges

Comment: @stark, `z` is not a constant. It is a static variable.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, when you want to understand things, you make tries and compare against books, etc. It is sometimes hard to abstract directly...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Err - I was using systems with virtual memory in the 80's, and on desktops in the 90's - and they had a (virtual) memory layout like that.  In fact, I would say that layout is pretty much universal these days.

Comment: run this on your machine: https://wandbox.org/permlink/t8kTLPVTXpf0nuIk and paste result to your question.

Comment: some improvements: https://wandbox.org/permlink/yiCgAzuDqsY1nPUb

Comment: @Snakienn Which operating system do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Your diagram is just conceptual. It does not reflect the complexities of linking, dynamic loading, relocation, and run time memory allocation.

Answer (score 1):

In practice, the heap data is *not* necessarily contiguous on recent Linux systems (and probably on most other desktop or server OSes). The [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) (VAS) wikipage has also a *simplified* figure.

On Linux systems, you can experiment with [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). Try `cat /proc/self/maps` which shows on the terminal the virtual address space of the (current) `cat` [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)). Try also `cat /proc/$$/maps` (to get the VAS of your current shell) and (as root) `cat /proc/$(pidof Xorg)/maps` (to get the VAS of your Xorg server). And try other `cat /proc/`*some-pid*`/maps` for various pids of various processes.

One of the explanation is that sometimes, `malloc` will call [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and not only [sbrk(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html). In particular, `malloc` of a *large* memory chunk will use `mmap` (I think the "threshold" for using `mmap` could be a `malloc` of several megabytes). And libraries and application programs can use `mmap` to access some file.

And `mmap` is using [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) so obviously won't give contiguous memory segments. Of course, an application (or the implementation of `free`) could sometimes use `munmap` to release memory. And [dynamic linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) (see [ld-linux(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.8.html) & [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) ...) also use `mmap` and `munmap`.

So **the virtual address space can be** (and often is) **made of *many discontinuous* memory segments** (sometimes thousands of them).

BTW, multi-threading also wants several memory segments. Generally each thread has its own `mmap`-ed stack space.

For example, I have some `mate-terminal` [terminal emulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) running as process of pid 2594.  Its process has 568 memory segments (i.e. lines in `/proc/2594/maps`). I won't spoil this answer by showing all of them. And the `firefox` browser process I am typing this answer in has 1229 lines in `/proc/1604/maps`, here are some of them:

```
27423e6e0000-27423e720000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0 
27423e720000-27423e730000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0 
27423e730000-27423e760000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0 
27423e760000-27423e780000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0 
27423e780000-27423e7c0000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0 
27423e7c0000-27423e7d0000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0 
27423e7d0000-27423e7e0000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
27423e7e0000-27423e7f0000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0 
7efed334d000-7efed3357000 r--p 00172000 08:01 11275829                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.23
7efed3357000-7efed3359000 rw-p 0017c000 08:01 11275829                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.23
7efed3359000-7efed335c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7efed335c000-7efed335f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1704007                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.24.so
7efed335f000-7efed355e000 ---p 00003000 08:01 1704007                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.24.so
7efed355e000-7efed355f000 r--p 00002000 08:01 1704007                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.24.so
```

So your picture is a *gross* simplification. I'm pretty sure that the fragmentation of the VAS also happens on other [operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system), notably for monster processes like e.g. your web browser.